# How to xUnit-Test in Rider? I'm getting error CS0246

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit, rider

I'm new to C#, and even more to unit testing in C#. Now I wanted to add unit tests to an application, but I can't seem to get it done in JetBrains Rider:

I created a new "Unit Test Project" inside my solution, besides my WPF application project. Rider installs `xunit`, `xunit.abstractions`, `xunit.assert`, `xunit.core`, `xunit.extensibility.core` and `xunit.extensibility.execution`. It also creates a `Tests.cs` class containing a `Test1()` method with a `[Fact]` attribute. Problem is: it immediately says `'Fact' is not an attribute`.

When building, it yields two [CS0246] Errors:

```
Tests.cs(8, 10): [CS0246] Der Typ- oder Namespacename "Fact" wurde nicht gefunden (fehlt eine using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweise?)
Tests.cs(8, 10): [CS0246] Der Typ- oder Namespacename "FactAttribute" wurde nicht gefunden (fehlt eine using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweise?)
```

I'm not sure what the exact English translation would be, but I guess you get the idea. What references are missing? Is this a bug in Rider?

I tried it with NUnit as well, with similar results.

Besides that: Do I need to follow any file structure or naming conventions for the tests to be autodetected?

Comment: add `using Xunit;` to the top of your Test.cs file. Rider should be able to do this for you if you hover the item with the error and look at the suggested fixes (ie, clicking the lightbulb that appears).

Comment: That's already there automatically, but it doesn't help. Rider gives no suggestions for the error.

Comment: Version of Rider? What .Net Version are you targeting? Have you opened the NuGet (Alt-7) tab and made sure to restore packages?

Comment: After hours of looking on my own, I got the solution 5 minutes after posting the question here: My application is targeting .NET 4.0. I correctly set the xUnit framework to 4.0 as well. Despite respecting that by installing older xunit packages, the template doesn't seem fully compatible with .NET 4.0. After changing the target framework to .NET 4.5 on my dummy project, everything is fine. Unfortunately, I cannot do that on my production project right now. What do I need to change in order to make it work in 4.0?
Rider is version 2018.1.2

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that the NuGet packages "xunit" and "xunit.runer.visualstudio" are installed (should have been installed automatically), and as Jonathon Chase mentioned add `using Xunit;` to the top of all files containing tests.

Comment: Should be `using Xunit;` as Jonathon says..., instead of `using XUnit;`